# The system cannot find the path specified - FirefoxDriver.exe

Tags: python

I was doing a sample selenium code with python 3.5 for opening the link https://www.python.org/ 
when i was executing the py it showed the followingf error.. But FirefoxDriver.exe exists in the given path.. And i've added that path in environmental variables too.. but still the error exists.. can anyone help me out of this..

My py sample.py :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox('C:\\pythonSelenium\\FirefoxDriver.exe')
browser.get(parameters['https://www.python.org/'])
```

==================== RESTART: C:/pythonSelenium/sample.py ====================
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:/pythonSelenium/sample.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox('C:\\pythonSelenium\\FirefoxDriver.exe')
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 134, in __init__
    firefox_profile = FirefoxProfile(firefox_profile)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile.py", line 78, in __init__
    ignore=shutil.ignore_patterns("parent.lock", "lock", ".parentlock"))
  File "C:\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 303, in copytree
    names = os.listdir(src)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\pythonSelenium\\FirefoxDriver.exe'
```

Comment: Try `browser = webdriver.Firefox(geckodriver='C:\\pythonSelenium\\FirefoxDriver.exe')`

Comment: if you open a python interactive session and then type `import os.path; os.path.exists('C:\\pythonSelenium\\FirefoxDriver.exe')`, what does it do?

Comment: os.path.exists() returns windows error..  [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\pythonSelenium\\FirefoxDriver.exe'

Comment: when using "driver = webdriver.Firefox()" its throwing "Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH." But when using "driver = webdriver.Firefox('C:\\pythonSelenium\\FirefoxDriver.exe')" its throwing  "[WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\pythonSelenium\\FirefoxDriver.exe'"

Answer (score 2):

Usually whenever a path is being given to the interpreter it should contain forwards slashes i.e `"C:**/****/****/**"` rather than backward slashes like the ones you used as described in the problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I recommend moving the second part into a comment. You can comment on your own post, did you know? Even below the 50 reputation for the general commenting privilege.

Comment: I edited for formatting, but maybe I did not get your intention completely correctly when it comes to `'` or `" `. Please double check and [edit] if necessary.

Comment: It is fine for either " or ' and i meant to say " only

Comment: Talking about the "System cannot the find the path specified", i am also getting the same when i am trying to invoke Firefox still have to figure out, if i find any solution for the i will let you know

Answer (score 1):

If you have the driver in PATH, you should be able to use it without providing arguments like this:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

You should also restart the system after you've changed environmental variables on Windows for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Here is my PATH C:\Python36;C:\Python36\Scripts;C:\pythonSelenium\geckodriver; ...  pythonSelenium is where the sample.py, FirefoxDriver and geckodriver exists..

Comment: when using "driver = webdriver.Firefox()" its throwing "Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH." But when using "driver = webdriver.Firefox('C:\\pythonSelenium\\FirefoxDriver.exe')" its throwing "[WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\pythonSelenium\\FirefoxDriver.exe'"

Comment: C:\pythonSelenium\geckodrive‌​r is a file, you should have C:\pythonSelenium in the PATH instead if that is the folder that contains the geckodriver.

Comment: I have added pythonSelenium path in the PATH and the file also exists in the path.. still it throwing "Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH"